# Eclipse CDT (C++ IDE) with Visual Studio 2013 Compiler

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio, gcc

First I want to say I don't know much about compilers.

I want to use Visual studio's Compiler. But I don't want to use Visual studio's IDE.
I would rather like to use CodeBlock's IDE or Eclipse's C++ IDE.

I DO NOT WANT TO USE CODEBLOCK'S MinGW GCC COMPILER (Because it compiles run lot's of things that it shouldn't).

So can I use CodeBlocks or Eclipse's IDE with Visual Studio 2013's c++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use MS Visual C++ toolchain in Eclipse :

[image]

And then appropiately configure it under *C/C++ Build -> Settings*

Comment: i did it then when i tried to build the project i showed error

Comment: @alalamin try to search and fix it and if _really_ lost come back with new post